# UIActionSheet doesn't show line separator

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uiactionsheet

I have a `UIActionSheet` with 4 buttons inside. The strange is that the last two buttons aren't separated by line like the others.

[image]

Probably I'm forgetting to set some property on action sheet ?
Or it's a bug ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The cancel Button is supposed to show at the last row. That is why there is no Line

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell your `UIActionSheet` which button index is for destructive action. To do that you can either create your destructive button as following:

```
sheet.destructiveButtonIndex = [sheet addButtonWithTitle:@"Annulla"];
```

Or if you want to set it after it has been created, you can do something like this:

```
sheet.destructiveButtonIndex = 0;
```

Where zero is the actual index of your destructive button.